# What is the simplest current example of how to update your twitter status from an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, twitter, oauth

What is the simplest current example of how to update your twitter status from an Android Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the actual code to send a tweet is simple using the Twitter4J library in Android :

```
public void sendTweet(SharedPreferences prefs,String msg) throws Exception {
    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret); 

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
    twitter.updateStatus(msg);
}
```

However, a lot of preperation is needed before you'll be able to succesfully execute these calls.

Take a look at [a 30 minute guide to integrating Twitter in your Android application](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/) that covers all steps required to tweet from an Android app :

- setup a twitter test account
- register a twitter application
- authenticate the user in your Android application using OAuth
- have the user send tweets from your Android application using the Twitter4J library

A sample project is included in the [AndroidTwitterSample GitHub repository](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample) to get you started.

Comment: I followed your blogpost integrating twitter into my app, but am unable to get it to actually post a tweet.  I've tried using both the twitter4j library you include in your sample code, and the newest stable version (3.0.3).  I don't have my code available at the moment, but do you have any boilerplate suggestions as to why it might not be working?  I will post a more in-depth description this evening if I am still unable to figure it out.